# Creating an AngularJS Directive for jQuery UI Button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Update**: Fiddle w/ full solution: http://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/VXBHG/

---

In efforts to compare and contrast KnockoutJS and AngularJS, I ran through the [KnockoutJS interactive tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/), and after each section, I'd rewrite it in AngularJS using what little I already knew + the [AngularJS reference](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/).

When I got to step 3 of the [Creating custom bindings](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=custombindings) tutorial, I figured it would be a good time to get spun up on Angular Directives and write a custom tag.  Then I failed miserably.

I'm up against two issues that I haven't been able to figure out.  I created a new Fiddle to try and wrap my head around what was going on...

- **1** ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/gWjXc/6/)): I figured out my scoping issue, but, is it possible to just passthrough `ng-click`?  The only way I could get it to work is to rename it to `jqb-click`  which is a little annoying.
- **2** ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/gWjXc/5/)): As soon as I applied `.button()` to my element, things went weird.  My guess is because both Angular and jQuery UI are manipulating the HTML.  I wouldn't expect this, but Angular seems to be providing its own `span` for my `button` (see line 21 of the JavaScript), and of course so is jQuery UI, which I would expect.  I hacked up the HTML to get it looking right, but even before that, none of the functionality works.  I still have the scope issue, and there's no template binding.  What am I missing?

I understand that there's an AngularUI project I should be taking a look at and I can probably pull off what I'm trying to do with just CSS, but at this point it's more about learning how to use Directives rather than thinking this is a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an isolated scope in a directive by setting the `scope` parameter, or let it use the parent scope by not setting it.

Since you want the `ng-click` from parent scope it is likely easiest for this instance to use the parent scope within directive:

One trick is to use `$timeout` within a directive before maniplulatig the DOM within a templated directive to give the DOM time to repaint before the manipulation, otherwise it seems that the elements don't exist in time.

I used an attribute to pass the text in, rather than worrying about transclusion compiling. In this manner the expression will already have been compiled when the template is added and the `link` callback provides easy access to the attributes.

```html
<jqbutton ng-click="test(3)" text="{{title}} 3"></jqbutton>
```

```js
angular.module('Components', [])
    .directive('jqbutton', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E', // says that this directive is only for html elements
        replace: true,        
        template: '<button></button>', 
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // turn the button into a jQuery button
            $timeout(function () {
                /* set text from attribute of custom tag*/
                element.text(attrs.text).button();
         }, 10);/* very slight delay, even using "0" works*/
        }
    };
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gWjXc/8/

Directives are very powerful, but also have a bit of a learning curve. Also in comparison of angular to knockout, angular is more of a meta framework that in the long run has far more flexibilty than knockout

Very helpful reading for understanding scope in directives:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/The-Nuances-of-Scope-Prototypal-Inheritance

Comment: Argh, so the absence of the directive controller and `ng-transclude`, let's scope for `ng-click` act normally... tricky.

Comment: no..directive controller can also use scope of parent controller also. It's all in whether you set `scope` param. `ng-transclude` doesn't impact scope either. `transclude` is essentially for determining whether to wrap existing html in tag within new template or abandoning it

Comment: Oh, I guess it was the fact that my controller defined a function named test, and then when I removed that, it was fact that I had `scope: {}` which the docs say creates an isolated scope.  That's what I get for copying from examples. :)  Thanks for your help.  Now that there's a text attribute, I was able to get `attrs.$observe` to work.  Cheers!

Comment: @charlieftl You said it was "easiest to use the parent scope".  Does that means it's definitely possible if I define my own scope?  I've gone back to using scope to get ng-Disabled to pass-through, but now I can't get my ng-Click to pass-through.  Mind taking a look?  http://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/VXBHG/5/

Comment: can do this `ng-click="$parent.test(4)"` but if nesting this in other directives like `ng-repeat` can get tricky tracking what `$parent` is

Comment: This also solves "TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery16202095036196988076' of undefined" encountered during testing a directive that uses jQuery UI.